# Why does SQL want you to select the column and THEN refer to the table?

Tags: sql

So this isn't a technical question, but rather questioning why a language is designed the way it is.

I've been learning SQL and one thing that's been bothering me greatly is how SQL asks you to name the column you want and THEN name the table you want to get it from. To me, it would make more sense that you refer to the parent body (which is the table) and THEN the column it has. But SQL seems to forces users to do it the other way around. Why?

I'm just curious as to why the language is designed this way.

```
SELECT column
FROM table
```

why not

```
FROM table
SELECT column
```

Comment: Lets not forget that the `WHERE` hits before the column selection too. `FROM <table> WHERE <field1>=<val> GROUP BY <field2> HAVING sum(<field3>)=<val> SELECT <field2>, sum(<field3>) ORDER BY <field2>` just feels gross though. Also, the optimization plan often moves the general order of operations around to optimize data retrieval (On RDBMS's that don't suck at optimization) so there is not any *real* order of operations.

Comment: Because the designers weren't that good.

Comment: "From the basket in the kitchen, Having no spots or bruises, can you Select the apples and oranges." Bleh.

Comment: If interesed, [here is a post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168595/where-can-i-find-the-first-standardization-of-sql-sql-86) on dba.stackexchange.com that may help tracking down the original ANSI SQL standard from 1986. Maybe there's something in there illuminating.

Comment: @JNevill: You are refering to a more-than-1000-pages document. I am sure there is SOMETHING illuminating in there :)

Comment: @juergend I'll bet it's super dry and boring though.

Comment: You might be interested in this pdf: http://www.joakimdalby.dk/HTM/sequel.pdf

Comment: It is well established that the SQL language was 'inspired' an IBM research project named SEQUEL. Relationalist Hugh Darwen hypothesises SEQUEL took is structure from an IBM product called GIS, the style of which was typical of scripting languages of the time ...that time being the late 1960s! You can read all about it in Darwen's free ebook 'SQL: A comparative Survey'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [this post](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/) useful. Starting with `FROM` is the most logical way to think about a query (Why would anyone write `SELECT` before knowing what to `SELECT` from?). However, SQL guidelines were designed as if your query were a *command*. Thus, you are commanding the system to `SELECT` the data for you, and the `FROM` further specifies that command.

Of course, the actual execution is distinct from the lexical and logical orders above.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is a descriptive language, not a procedural language. It *describes* the result set being produced. And, you can think of that result set as a report, with column headers.

As such, the basic querying construct returns those column headers. The rest of the query describes how they are produced.

Answer (score 3):

SQL tries to mimic English language to some extent, so that it feels natural to formulate the query.

In spoken English you would say something like "I want the names of the employees". You would not say "I want of the employees their names" or something like that.

But you are right, it might have been a good idea to have the query represent the order of execution. And "From the employee table I want the names" would not be so far off the mark :-)